# How to optimize this kind of code

Tags: javascript, trie

How could i get the `mark` and `mary` by using `searchstring` and `current_object`?  I have to use `array_push` for pushing new `searchstring` and `current_object` for create new output like `mark` and `mary`.

```js
function get_suggestion_array_from_object(searchstring, current_object) {
  var suggestion_array = [];
  console.log(current_object);
}

var test_searchstring = 'Ma';
var test_current_object_string = '{"r":{"k":0,"y":0}}';

var test_current_object = JSON.parse(test_current_object_string);

get_suggestion_array_from_object(test_searchstring, test_current_object);
```

Comment: why did you tag this question with 'jquery'? what is the meaning of the properties r, k, y in `test_current_object_string`?

Comment: Please post this over on the Code Review SE.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure at all what it is you're asking but just a simple optimization would be this:

instead of writing a JSON string and then parsing it to an object, write the object immediatly:

```
var test_current_object_string = '{"r":{"k":0,"y":0}}';
var test_current_object = JSON.parse(test_current_object_string);
```

into:

```
var test_current_object = {r:{k:0, y:0}};
```